# What is the simplest way to include a hidden field when using Django's generic editing views

Tags: django, python-3.x

I would like to pass a hidden form field but still take advantage of Django's `Createview` and not have to build a custom form. Something like:

```
class ObjectCreateView(CreateView):
   model = Object
   fields = ['title','content','rating']
```

Where I'd like rating to be hidden. I thought something like:

```
fields['rating'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

might work, but of course, it doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to pass this as a hidden field?

Comment: It's a field that stores the value of a rating, but I'm using javascript to display stars. I want it to be available so I can set its value, but it's an integer and I don't want the default display django gives me that lets me request a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass `CreateView` and modify the `get_form` method:

```
class ObjectCreateView(CreateView):
     model = Object
     fields = ['title','content','rating']

     def get_form(self, form_class=None):
         form = super().get_form( form_class)
         form.fields['rating'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
         return form
```

Invaluable reference for CBVs: [Classy Class Based Views](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/)

Comment: If you get an error about forms not being defined then just do `from django import forms`

Answer (score 0):

We can subclass the `CreateView` to take widgets into account:

```
class WidgetCreateView(CreateView):
    widgets = {}

    def get_form_class(self):
        """Return the form class to use in this view."""
        if self.fields is not None and self.form_class:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "Specifying both 'fields' and 'form_class' is not permitted."
            )
        if self.form_class:
            return self.form_class
        else:
            if self.model is not None:
                # If a model has been explicitly provided, use it
                model = self.model
            elif getattr(self, 'object', None) is not None:
                # If this view is operating on a single object, use
                # the class of that object
                model = self.object.__class__
            else:
                # Try to get a queryset and extract the model class
                # from that
                model = self.get_queryset().model
            if self.fields is None:
                raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                    "Using ModelFormMixin (base class of %s) without "
                    "the 'fields' attribute is prohibited." % self.__class__.__name__
                )
            return model_forms.modelform_factory(
                model,
                fields=self.fields,
                widgets=self.widgets
            )
```

then we can subclass this to:

```
class ObjectCreateView(WidgetCreateView):
    model = Object
    fields = ['title','content','rating']
    widgets = {
        'rating': forms.HiddenInput
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this very thing and the field still appears on the form. My code:

class ObjCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Object
    fields = ['title','content','rating']
    widgets = {
        'rating': forms.HiddenInput
    }

Comment: @Dele: but you first need to make a `WidgetCreateView`. Note that we *subclassed* the `CreateView`, and slightly altered the `get_form_class` behavior. That is the entire point. It is thus not the `widget = ...` that does the magic. It is the `get_form_class`, and we simply then override the `widget` attribute to inject different values.

Comment: @Dele: the idea is thus to make the modified logic *reusable*, such that you can later use the `WidgetCreateView`, in several class-based views.

Comment: I get you now. Yes, I do like your solution, it's neat. Thank you.